# I don't fully understand onClickListeners

Tags: android, anonymous-inner-class

So when we set an onClickListener to, say, a Button, it looks something like this.

```
private Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);

myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        //do this
    }

});
```

So we're creating a nameless anonymous class when we state new View.OnClickListener... and implementing the OnClickListener interface / and overriding it's onClick method. What I don't understand, is if we have no reference to this anon class, because it's nameless, how does the onClick() method get called? I've only ever implemented an anonymous class to override certain methods in said class, like this:

```
public class Foo{
    public void bar(){
        //do something
    }
}


Foo foo = new Foo(){
    @Override
    public void bar(){
        //do something else
    }
}
```

This makes perfect sense to me because now, anytime I use the "foo" reference to call the bar() method, that reference will use the overridden version of bar. In the case of the Button, there's no reference to onClick(). I'm beyond confused about this.

Comment: The button holds the reference to the object with the overridden onClick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it helps your understanding, you could rewrite to this:

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        //do this
    }
};
myButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

The button holds the reference after listener goes out of scope, and can call the `onClick` callback on the held listener object.

Comment: I *think* I figured it out, just one last thing. Does the setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener L) method invoke L.onClick() ?

Comment: It likely stores off the listener to call the 'onClick' method when the user clicks the button

Comment: So in other words, onClick() is invoked by calling it via the interface later on? For example, the button has the method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener L) , L being the variable name for the OnClickListener interface. I can now use L.onClick() to invoke onClick(), does that seem right?

Comment: Thanks a ton! this was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> What I don't understand, is if we have no reference to this anon class, because it's nameless, how does the onClick() method get called?

`myButton` is holding onto the instance of the anonymous inner class that you created. `myButton`, therefore, can call `onClick()` on it.

Comment: Hmm, but if I attempt to call myButton.onClick(); it doesn't seem to recognize that method.

Comment: @JoshDerk: That is because `myButton` is a `Button`. `myButton` **holds** your `OnClickListener`. `myButton` itself is not your `OnClickListener`, and `Button` does not have an `onClick()` method.

Comment: I *think* I figured it out, your comment helped me. I drew up a little something here.

Answer (score 1):

The onclick event is called in the button object and this object delegates to your anonymous class onclick with the reference you set.